# How to replace Ubuntu 32-bit with 64-bit in dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit, uninstall, windows-8, 32-bit

I just got a new Lenovo Ideapad y580 running Windows 8. Today I took my first crack at dual booting Ubuntu on it.  Since 32 bit is marked recommended, that is what I downloaded, but apparently it is not compatible with the UEFI windows 8 requires, so it never properly installed. I have read that I will need a Windows 8 recovery disk to rehabilitate my machine after uninstalling Ubuntu, but my machine did not come with one, and it would take a long time to get one shipped to me at the location I'm at. What is the best way to remove Ubuntu 32 bit and replace it with 64 bit while leaving Windows 8 intact?

Comment: You can download and burn [the recovery disk from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only).  Once Windows 8 is working again you can install Ubuntu by following the instructions in this question: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/107450)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Ubuntu64bit (or better: [Linux-Secure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxSecureRemix)64bit, because it already contains Boot-Repair that you will need in step3 below), and burn it to DVD or liveUSB
2. Boot on it, then install it above your current Ubuntu32bit [this way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation).
3. Then reboot the PC. If Grub does not access both Ubuntu and Windows, follow [this procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) to fix UEFI boot.